# Warning message errors in c

Tags: c, warnings

```
warning: unknown escape sequence: '\!' [enabled by default]
  printf("\\ this is a back-slash character\!\n");
         ^
w1p2.c:25:9: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\!' [enabled by default]
  printf("%% this is a percent sign character\!\n");
         ^
w1p2.c:26:9: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\!' [enabled by default]
  printf("\" this is a double - quote character\!\n");
```

I made a simple `printf` program and I keep getting these messages.
Exactly what's going on and how do I fix it?

I tried using the `\` symbol before it but didn't do much.

Comment: It's telling you that `\!` is not valid. There's no need to escape `!` so remove the `\ ` before the `!`.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem.

Comment: Fang Sum, good question with an exact copy of the error message.

Answer (score 1):

> Exactly what's going on and how do I fix it?

Only some characters may be escaped (C11 [§6.4.4.4](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4), [§6.4.5](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5), [§6.4.3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.3)).
`!` is not one of them and a `\` is not needed to print a `!`.

```
// printf("\\ this is a back-slash character\!\n");
printf("\\ this is a back-slash character!\n");
//                                       ^
```

---

simple-escape-sequence: one of

```
\’ \" \? \\  
\a \b \f \n \r \t \v
```

octal-escape-sequence:

```
\ octal-digit
\ octal-digit octal-digit
\ octal-digit octal-digit octal-digit
```

hexadecimal-escape-sequence:

```
\x hexadecimal-digit
hexadecimal-escape-sequence hexadecimal-digit
```

universal-character-name:

```
\u hex-quad
\U hex-quad hex-quad
```